# Generate LI with Json Objects get from PHP

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, get

I have a little problem. I've got json datas from a `$.get()` request with jQuery

Here is the output :

```
[
    {"name":"Silver","price":525,"per_month":"20","first_invoice":"20"},
    {"name":"Gold","price":500,"per_month":"50","first_invoice":"0"},
    {"name":"Avion","price":750,"per_month":"10","first_invoice":"10"}
]
```

I try to generate an UL with an LI for each objetcs...

I write this little code :

```
//send get request
    $.get(
        url, 
        { 'dst': dst, 'price':price },
        function(data) {

            var objects = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            var items = [];

            jQuery.each(objects, function(){
                console.log(this);

                items.push('<li id="' + this.name + '">' + this.price + '</li>');
            }); 

            jQuery('<ul/>', {
                'class': 'my-new-list',
                html: items.join('')
            }).appendTo('#results');                
        }
    );
```

When i use `console.log()`each objects are logged by firebug : no error... it works.

This is the `items.push()` and the `appendTo()` which generate nothing... no error in the console... no append in my `#results` div...

I'm sure I do something wrong. Can anyone help me ?

**Update**

With the help of Fabrício Matté (answer after), the problem was the iframe.

```
jQuery('<ul/>', {
                'class': 'my-new-list',
                html: items.join('')
            }).appendTo(jQuery('body').find('#results'));
```

That works =)

Sey you soon Stackoverflow Community

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/WaDkT/.

Comment: Yup it does seem to work fine with the original code. Make sure your `#results` is in the DOM and your `console.log` shows what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit:** As per João's comment, your original code is working perfectly fine. Make sure that:

1. `#result` is in the DOM when you try to append the data;
2. `jQuery.parseJSON(data)` returns an array of objects;
3. jQuery is properly included and there are no syntax errors before executing that line;
4. I rewrote the code slightly to make it easier to read as well:

   ```
   var objects = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

   var items = '';

   jQuery.each(objects, function(){
       items += '<li id="' + this.name + '">' + this.price + '</li>';
   }); 

   jQuery('<ul/>', {
       'class': 'my-new-list'
   }).html(items).appendTo('#results');
   ```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/VmW74/1/)

---

### **EDIT**

As per OP's comment, you can't use a selector to select elements inside of an `iframe` without referencing its `document` first. Here's how I'd do it with [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
//replace the $('iframe') with ID/class selector if possible
jQuery('iframe').contents().find('#results').append(jQuery('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list'
}).html(items));
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/VmW74/4/)

**Note** that this does not work if the `iframe` document is from a different host, port or protocol.
[Same Origin Policy reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: It's indeed easier to read, but I don't think it's the cause of the problem.

Comment: Mhm, I tested the original code in a fiddle and it didn't seem to work. I'll review it to check what else I changed, if anything.

Comment: As i said in my last comment, the number 1,2 and 3 of your check list is Ok for me. The only thing is that the page works in an "iframe element" created by Fancybox... Maybe the dom can't write in an iframe ?

Comment: @Raphaël Oh I see. It can yes, but not the usual way. `#results` is inside the iframe and you're trying to write from outside of it? In that case you should do something like `$('iframe').contents().find('#results')` - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/VmW74/3/) (it's better if you can get the iframe from an ID or class instead, of course). **NOTE:** This won't work if the iframe is from another domain due to same origin policy, in that case you just can't do that without some really ugly hacks which aren't recommended.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté : you save my day... instead `appendTo('#results')` I write `jQuery('body').find('#results')` and it works like a charm. I update my answer with the answer. I didn't know this functionnality =)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<ul>')
    .addClass('my-new-list')
    .html($.map(objects, function(el) {
        return '<li id="' + el.name + '">' + el.price + '</li>';
    }).join("\n"))
    .appendTo('#results');
```

Comment: sorry but this doen't answer to my question =)